# android: get imageview in code

Tags: android

how can i get a variable on the imageview that i have defined in a layout.xml in the code?

thanks!

Comment: Practice proper capitalization. Don't begin a question with “hello, ”.

Comment: @jonathan, what's wrong with saying hello?

Comment: @schwiz: You know it! :)

Comment: If you do, please capitalize it and follow it either by a period or an exclamation point (period is preferable). I'm sorry for being such a grammar/usage bitch, but poorly-written SO questions drive me crazy. Please ignore me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give the `ImageView` an id and then use the `findViewById()` method

```
 ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.someid);
```

Note, the `findViewById()` method has to be called from a `Context` object (Activity, etc)

Comment: Correct answer, only you also have to cast it to an ImageView. I made an edit.